# How to join multiple rows in one single row with custom column names

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I'm working on a rock, paper, scissors game, I've a table to save round results, but I'm saving a row per player in every round, so if there are N players they will be also N rows per round.

What I want is to show a report of how's going the rounds but I don't want to show N rows per round, I want to show a single one with N columns showing player data and a final column showing the name of the winner.

Currently this is the report I'm generating:

```
| Round |      Player       |  Shape   | Won |
|-------|-------------------|----------|-----|
|     1 | george (Player 1) | Rock     |   0 |
|     1 | wendy (Player 2)  | Paper    |   1 |
|     2 | george (Player 1) | Rock     |   0 |
|     2 | wendy (Player 2)  | Rock     |   0 |
|     3 | george (Player 1) | Paper    |   1 |
|     3 | wendy (Player 2)  | Rock     |   0 |
|     4 | george (Player 1) | Scissors |   0 |
|     4 | wendy (Player 2)  | Rock     |   1 |
|     5 | george (Player 1) | Scissors |   0 |
|     5 | wendy (Player 2)  | Scissors |   0 |
```

My expected result is something like this:

```
| Round | Player1Name | Player2Name | Player1Shape | Player2Shape |   PlayerWinner   |
|-------|-------------|-------------|--------------|--------------|------------------|
|     1 | george      | wendy       | Paper        | Rock         | Wendy (Player2)  |
|     2 | george      | wendy       | Rock         | Rock         | Draw (No Winner) |
|     3 | george      | wendy       | Paper        | Rock         | George (Player1) |
|     4 | george      | wendy       | Scissors     | Rock         | Wendy (Player2)  |
|     5 | george      | wendy       | Scissors     | Scissors     | Draw (No Winner) |
```

I don't know if this kind of report is possible I'm not expert in T-SQL, I'm using SQL Server 2016.

Here you can see a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a09a1/1) with 3 tables very similar to the real model with test data and the T-SQL code to generate the first report.

I will appreciate your help

Comment: If you're getting results like that, i'd say there's probably a fundamental design problem underlying your query. so work on changing your schema rather than trying to fix this output, will save you time in the long run

Comment: @Tanner Thanks for your comment, as I said I'm not SQL/DB expert, I just can't change right now the whole design because many things depends on it, I can change the report as I want because there are no dependencies just a SQL Query but changing the whole model will impact many things

Comment: well sooner or later these flaws in your design will become a pain to explain and manage, good luck!

Comment: @Tanner thanks for your suggestion but I need to solve my current problems and perhaps later I will think in the future ones

Answer (score 2):

Using conditional aggregation and some string manipulation:

```
select 
    Round
  , Player1Name  = max(case when left(right(player,2),1)='1' then left(Player,charindex(' (',Player)) end)
  , Player2Name  = max(case when left(right(player,2),1)='2' then left(Player,charindex(' (',Player)) end)
  , Player1Shape = max(case when left(right(player,2),1)='1' then Shape end)
  , Player2Shape = max(case when left(right(player,2),1)='2' then Shape end)
  , PlayerWinner = max(case when won = 1 then Player else 'Draw (NoWinner)' end)
from t
group by Round
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/DRPRZV13212

returns:

```
+-------+-------------+-------------+--------------+--------------+-------------------+
| Round | Player1Name | Player2Name | Player1Shape | Player2Shape |   PlayerWinner    |
+-------+-------------+-------------+--------------+--------------+-------------------+
|     1 | george      | wendy       | Rock         | Paper        | wendy (Player 2)  |
|     2 | george      | wendy       | Rock         | Rock         | Draw (NoWinner)   |
|     3 | george      | wendy       | Paper        | Rock         | george (Player 1) |
|     4 | george      | wendy       | Scissors     | Rock         | wendy (Player 2)  |
|     5 | george      | wendy       | Scissors     | Scissors     | Draw (NoWinner)   |
+-------+-------------+-------------+--------------+--------------+-------------------+
```

---

Update: Initially the sql fiddle wouldn't load, but once it did I copied the schema to rextester (only 3 rounds in fiddle data though):

```
select 
    R.RoundNumber as Round
  , Player1Name  = max(case when p.Number=1 then p.Name end)
  , Player2Name  = max(case when p.Number=2 then p.Name end)
  , Player1Shape = max(case when p.Number=1 then r.PlayerShape end)
  , Player2Shape = max(case when p.Number=2 then r.PlayerShape end)
  , PlayerWinner = max(case when r.IsWinner = 1 then concat(p.Name, ' (Player ',p.Number,')')
    else 'Draw (NoWinner)' end)
from [dbo].[Game] as G
  inner join [dbo].[Player] as P 
    on G.Token = P.GameToken
  inner join [dbo].[Round] as R 
    on P.Token = R.PlayerToken
where G.Token = 'A0cc2B30-6D2D-446F-9D44-58ba08F7eae5'
group by RoundNumber
order by R.RoundNumber asc
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/KUA90275

returns:

```
+-------+-------------+-------------+--------------+--------------+-------------------+
| Round | Player1Name | Player2Name | Player1Shape | Player2Shape |   PlayerWinner    |
+-------+-------------+-------------+--------------+--------------+-------------------+
|     1 | george      | wendy       | Rock         | Paper        | wendy (Player 2)  |
|     2 | george      | wendy       | Rock         | Rock         | Draw (NoWinner)   |
|     3 | george      | wendy       | Paper        | Rock         | george (Player 1) |
+-------+-------------+-------------+--------------+--------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: The SSMS is opening .. and ur answer is appeared :D, good work (y)

Comment: this is kinda covering up the flaws in the design i'd say, worth at least mentioning that.

Comment: @Tanner You already mentioned that in the comments to the question, so I didn't feel the need to repeat you.

Comment: I'm thinking of future readers that might not read the comments

Comment: @SqlZim Thanks for your code, I'm just wondering if there is a way to generate dynamically the columns based on the records from the Player table? That in the case a game have more than 2 players...